# How to programmatically move files from internal memory to sdcard in android?

Tags: android, file, move

How to move files from device's internal memory to external memory in android? Please provide code examples. My code is below

```
    private void moveFile(File file, File dir) throws IOException {
    File newFile = new File(dir, file.getName());
    FileChannel outputChannel = null;
    FileChannel inputChannel = null;
    try {
        outputChannel = new FileOutputStream(newFile).getChannel();
        inputChannel = new FileInputStream(file).getChannel();
        inputChannel.transferTo(0, inputChannel.size(), outputChannel);
        inputChannel.close();
        file.delete();
    } finally {
        if (inputChannel != null) inputChannel.close();
        if (outputChannel != null) outputChannel.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this not working ?

Comment: @george D this is moving the file but the file was not able to opened. Its showing size is zero

Comment: Can you please post the `dir` variable's value? Also post the directory in the external memory that you wish to write the file to. Also check if you have the      `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` declared in your manifest. And in the end check if you get any IOException in your stacktrace.

Comment: Yes I added permission previously itself and the dir variable is    File dir=new File("/storage/sdcard1/Bluetooth/example.jpg/");   this is the line I used@george

Comment: Remove the trailing slash from your path. It is not needed since example.png is not a directory. Actually do not hardcode the path to the sd card cause it might differ from device to device. Try `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get the path to sdcard then add any trailing path in the end. Please see this
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: I've posted this as an answer, please accept it if it helped you so that future visitors will be able to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the trailing slash from your path. It is not needed since example.png is not a directory. Actually do not hardcode the path to the sd card cause it might differ from device to device. Try Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to get the path to sdcard then add any trailing path in the end.

Please take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()).